# Que forma simples posso executar os programas em python?

Tags: python-3.x

Minha pergunta é bem nível novato, desculpem-me. Uso pycharm mas estou aberto a outras sugestões melhores de acordo com meu problema.
   Gostaria de executar o código no próprio interpretador, mas segundo o livro que pratico, todos os exemplos como um que postarei logo a seguir, segue a metodologia diferente daquela que eu estava adaptado, pode ser da minha parte: Falta de costume; ou o livro tem esta proposta exatamente como desafio; ou estou fazendo mal-proveito da leitura. O que me incomoda e dificulta meu aprendizado é o código ser descrito num arquivo e a chamada dos métodos etc... feitas em outro, no terminal (>>>). 
    Então a todo momento fico forçado a copiar o código para o terminal. 
- Exemplo retirado do livro Python Fluente(Luciano Ramalho).

```
import collections
from random import choice

Card  = collections.namedtuple('Card',['rank', 'suit'])

class FrenchDeck:
    ranks =  [str(n) for n in range (2, 11)] + list ('JQKA')
    suits = 'spades diamonds clubs hearts'.split()
    suits_values = dict(spades=3, hearts=2, diamonds=1, clubs=0)

    def __init__(self):
        self._cards = [Card(rank, suit) for suit in self.suits
                                    for rank in self.ranks]


    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._cards)

    def __getitem__(self, position):
        return self._cards[position]
```

Aqui é  forma como é chamado o código para executar;
 
Executando:

```
>>> beer_dark = Card('7', 'diamonds')
>>> beer_card
Card(rank='7', suit='diamonds')

>>> deck = FrenchDeck()
>>> len(deck)
52
```

A medida que o código cresce ora acrescenta no arquivo ora ajustes no terminal. Pessoal, permitam-me saber se existe uma forma prática ou terei de adaptar o código, incrementando parâmetros aonde não houver para que eu possa executá-lo de uma só vez no interpretador.

Comment: Não conseguirei elaborar a resposta no momento, mas o que você pode fazer é criar dois arquivos: um que define a classe, que você já possui, e outro onde você colocará os códigos de execução. Para executar, basta rodar o arquivo de execução pelo interpretador do Python. Assim, qualquer alteração na execução você poderá fazer editando o arquivo, sem ter que reescrever todo o código no terminal.

Comment: Usa Linux, Mac ou Windows?